# Change grouping of store ExtJS

Tags: extjs

I have the following code:

```
Ext.define('MyStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    config: {
        //proxy and domain properties
        model: 'Contact' ,
        autoLoad: true,
        groupField: 'Name'
    }
});
```

I want to reset the grouping on 'Phone'. 
How to change grouping of data from store and reload after?

Comment: Isn't that some Touch code? If so, you should take care of tagging accordingly, Ext and Touch are full of discrepancies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [`group`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-group) method of the store. It will [clear the previously set groupers](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/source/Store.html#Ext-data-Store-method-group).